# Printing a custom NSTextView

Tags: macos, nstextview, nsprintoperation

Trying to setup printing from a custom NSTextView (which uses TextKit components). This is what I now do using a second view:

```
override func printView(_ sender: Any?) {
    let printTextView = MyTextView(frame: view.frame, textContainer: self.textContainer)
    let op = NSPrintOperation(view: printTextView)

    op.run()
}
```

So when the Print Dialog appears, it shows the correct text with attributes and layout, but the original `MyTextView` is suddenly empty, as if the text was moved from the view to the print view.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can text views share a `textContainer`?

Comment: Ah, good point - let me go dig into that. Probably need to recreate the `layoutManager` and 'textStorage` as well.

Comment: Alternatively, I am going to explore copying the whole view using `NSCoder` and friends.

Comment: The same thing happens when printing an `NSTableView` - it disappears from its window. Maybe the original tableView (or its VC) gets deallocated when the Print Dialog appears?

Comment: I don't think `NSTableView` has anything to do with `textContainer`. Ask a new question about printing a table view please.

Comment: Yes, I understand they have nothing to do with each other. Just thinking out loud if something else could be going on since it happens with both an `NSTextView` and an `NSTableView`. I'll keep digging.